# Redis Docker compose Can't handle RDB format version 10

Tags: docker, redis

I can't start redis container in my docker-compose file. I know that docker-compose file is OK, because my colleagues can start the project successfully. I read that there is a solution to delete dump.rdb file. But I can't find it. I use Windows machine. Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Error
2023-02-09 16:41:28 1:M 09 Feb 2023 13:41:28.699 # Can't handle RDB format version 10

Redis in docker_compose:

redis:

```
container_name: redis
hostname: redis
image: redis:5.0
ports:
  - "6379:6379"
volumes:
  - redis:/data
restart: always
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to specify something there. I also faced such an issue, and if the solution to remove the volume is working, you can't delete a volume in use, which means you are to remove the container using the volume first...for most container / volumes, that's not an issue, but regarding to redis, if for example you are trying to downgrade your version, then it will force you to do the same operation with your database container leading you to dump your database as you will have to rebuild it again.

So my point is do not run these commands blindly and prepare yourself a dumpp of your database first.

Even better if you need to work on multiple version of and environment for the same project, instead of rebuilding your docker all the time, consider taking 2 differents projets so as your database will keep sage.

Answer (score 9):

The solution was very simple:

```
docker volume ls
docker volume rm <volume_name>
```

Comment: Should I remove everything or something concrete?

Comment: @chakzefir , docker volume rm your_redis_volume. But you can remove all volumes, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac M2 running the docker compose, the solution was removing .datastore directory in the root of project

Comment: What does this accomplish exactly?

Comment: I have bind mount like that:
`    volumes:
      - ./.datastore/redis:/data`
removing this dir resolve the issue but I am not sure why