# Can't handle RDB format version 10 on docker compose

Tags: docker, redis

I have exactly the same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75399597/redis-docker-copmpose-cant-handle-rdb-format-version-10) except the proposed solution doesn't work for me.

When I run `docker container ls` , I get an empty table, there are no containers running.

I also tried `docker volume ls` to see which volumes are there, and delete them with `docker volume rm 522220763c3b077347006fd288b1695b75c36b8d2d9e614fddb8a358a3c3bc49` but I get an error saying that the volume is in use.

It seems I have a ghost docker process running.

I tried resetting my laptop, killing Docker altogether, nothing works.

This was working a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the volumes were created by docker compose, so I was able to kill them like this

`docker-compose down --volumes`

After that, I was able to run redis on docker.